# Missing posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

Hi folks, recently joined to help out at Stack Overflow (mainly with Java based questions).

I noticed that all the numbers of posts under the tags I regularly visit (applet, jnlp, swing, java) have dropped dramatically.

One specific example is the Java tag, which was showing over 70,000 posts, but now only displays around 11,000.

Did a search here for "missing post" as well as "content gone", as well as looked through the first 5 pages of recent posts (which admittedly only took me through to 'yesterday') and could see no comment or discussion here on the matter.  My search skills must be lacking.

1. What has happened?
2. Has this been discussed elsewhere?  (I am surprised that it would not have been, on such an active, community driven set of forums).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I check [the Java tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), I see 90,430 questions total. No posts have vanished.

However, if I specifically look at the [unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50), I report 11,691. It seems that you're just looking at that tab, which means that you won't see every question by virtue that the majority are answered.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.  I must have done something odd, since I have been doing the 'same' actions all the time to see the change.  I'll try and figure where I went wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: OK - after re-reading your answer carefully and a close inspection of the UI I noticed the tabs in which I'd flipped from 'newest' to 'unanswered'.  I'll take my stab at questions that have already got answers, so long as I have a better (or at least alternate and viable) solution.  ;)  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.