# Why do questions/tagged/XYZ and tags/XYZ/faq not show the same number?

Tags: support, tags, frequent-tab

These two links indicate a different number of questions with that tag.

- [questions/tagged/visual-c++-2008-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b-2008-express)

  - shows "1 questions tagged `visual-c++-2008-express`"
- [tags/visual-c++-2008-express/faq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-c%2b%2b-2008-express/faq),

  - shows "16 questions tagged `visual-c++-2008-express`"

Looks like a bug to me.  First, because the numbers are different.  Second, because there are two different URLs to get the same info.  Or is it not supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 4):

The FAQ tab only shows questions that are, well, "frequently asked". This is determined by the number of links towards that question, if I'm not mistaken.

Not all questions get linked, so not all questions within a tag will qualify to be in the FAQ tab.

Comment: So 16 of the 1 questions with that tag are frequently asked?  Hmm....  I guess I understand what the FAQ tab is for now (makes sense) but still seems like there's a problem since `faq > total`

Comment: @Dan Separate issue: see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75226/missing-posts-on-stack-overflow/75227#75227). You're viewing a tab that isn't showing all of the questions with that tag.

Comment: I still think something is wrong.  If you look at your answer to that other question you linked to, and click the link that should show 90,xxx Java questions, it now only shows 9,xxx.  Actually, that makes me think it is backwards, because the "faq" link says there are 91,xxx Java questions.  Note: I'm talking about the "faq" link (next to the "about the java tag" link), not the "faq" tab.

Comment: @Dan - I think you misunderstood Grace here, make sure to read the question linked.  You're on a tab that filters questions, e.g. unanswered, faq, or featured...these won't show **all** the questions.  The tab you're on is remembered, not a default...so you'll need to click another tab to change, like "newest".