# Could SO tag counts be broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do questions/tagged/XYZ and tags/XYZ/faq not show the same number?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75264/why-do-questions-tagged-xyz-and-tags-xyz-faq-not-show-the-same-number)

On SO, the "questions tagged" count is way different than the number shown in the tag list. For example, [SproutCore Collection Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795862/sproutcore-collection-sorting) shows "sproutcore-controllers × 6" while [sproutcore-controllers](/questions/tagged/sproutcore-controllers) shows "1 questions tagged" (and indeed, there is only one question displayed).

Since the numbers match on other sites I've checked (Meta and Math.SE, Programmers.SE, etc.), while every tag I've checked (e.g. [c#] shows 66,635 in one place and 271245 in the other) on SO has the mismatch, I suspect this is a bug in the tag cache.

Comment: No repro; I see 6 questions. My "Tagged Questions" page for the [tag:sproutcore-controllers] tag looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zdfl7.png).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do questions/tagged/XYZ and tags/XYZ/faq not show the same number?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75264/why-do-questions-tagged-xyz-and-tags-xyz-faq-not-show-the-same-number), [Missing posts on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75226/missing-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check which sort tab you're on.

The [faq tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sproutcore-controllers?sort=faq&pagesize=50) shows only 1 question; but other tabs (like [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sproutcore-controllers/info) and [votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sproutcore-controllers?sort=votes&pagesize=50)) show all 6 questions as expected.

Comment: Sure enough, that's it! Why is it defaulting to the FAQ tab for me on SO, but Newest on other sites?

Comment: @Gabe That I'm not sure about. I think it defaults to the last tab you looked at for any tag.

Comment: Yes, it does remember the last active tab. Which leads to strange usability problems, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab), or [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken), or [this other one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90716/you-are-on-the-featured-tab-but-theres-no-featured-tab).